# Как использовать один экземпляр класса для нескольких статических методов?

Tags: c#

//Собственно, сам класс, экземпляр которого хочу использовать

```
    public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SurName{ get; set; }
    public float Age { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
}
```

//Сама программа

```
class Program
{

    Person pers = new Person();//Экземпляр класса, который хочу использовать

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Anketa();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Anketa()//Данный метод, насколько я понимаю, должен быть статическим, ибо нельзя использовать нестатический метод в статическом?
    {
        //(0)
        Console.WriteLine("Заполните, пожалуйста, анкету:");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите ваше имя:");
        pers.Name = Console.ReadLine();//(1)
        Console.WriteLine("Введите вашу фамилию:");
        pers.SurName = Console.ReadLine();//(2)
        Console.WriteLine("Введите ваш возраст:");
        pers.Age = ReadLineAndConvertationToFloat();//(3)
        Console.WriteLine("Введите ваш рост:");
        pers.Height = ReadLineAndConvertationToFloat();//(4)
        Console.WriteLine("Введите ваш вес:");
        pers.Weight = ReadLineAndConvertationToFloat();//(5)
```

//Ну, собственно, сама проблема: Компилятор сразу начинает ругаться на строки (1,2,3,4,5), говоря, что "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Program.pers" требуется ссылка на объект".

//Всё работает, если создать объект pers в строке (0), но тогда я не смогу использовать его в других методах.

//Как решается данная проблема, описанная выше?

```
        Console.WriteLine($"Ваше имя: {pers.Name};\nВаша фамилия:  {pers.SurName};\nВаш возраст: {pers.Age};\nВаш рост: {pers.Height};\nВаш вес: {pers.Weight}.");
    }
```

//Метод для преобразования строки в число (не обращайте на него внимания)

```
    static float ReadLineAndConvertationToFloat()
    {
        bool isFloat = false;
        float res;
        do
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            isFloat = float.TryParse(s, out res);
            if (!isFloat) Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не число! повторите попытку!");
        } while (!isFloat);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: можете передавать желаемый объект в качестве аргумента для статических методов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте сам экземпляр тоже статическим:

```
static Person pers = new Person();
```

Либо избавьтесь от статики вовсе:

```
static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run();

void Run()
{
    Anketa();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Другой вариант - использовать объекты с ограниченной областью видимости, например, создавать `Person pers = new Person();` внутри метода `Anketa`, а по завершении метода возвращать его `return pers;` (если он нужен будет дальше)